# Why can't I run my shell script to list users?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

```
users='awk  '{print $1}' /etc/passwd | sort -u'

for user in $users
 do
      echo " - $user"
done
```

this is my shell script . Problem is that show's an error.
the error is ---> `users: command not found` 
please give me the solution frinds

Comment: Where did you put the script?  Is it somewhere in your PATH?  Is it marked as executable?

Answer (score 3):

With the code the way it is now I see that you're not assigning the output of the `awk|sort` command to the variable (maybe you wanted to use ` instead of ' ?)

This works:

```
#!/bin/bash

users=$(awk  '{print $1}' /etc/passwd | sort -u)

for user in $users
do
      echo " - $user"
done
```

Although you should be aware that `/etc/passwd` is not separated by spaces, so `awk '{print $1}'` won't give you the user's name (which maybe is what you wanted)

**Edit:**

As per @[Andy Lester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8454/andy-lester)'s comment to your question: If you save this code in a file (let's say `/tmp/myscript.bash`) to run it you have to type in a terminal:

```
/bin/bash /tmp/myscript.bash
```

or, since it starts with `#!/bin/bash` (read [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html#sect_01_05)) you could make it executable (using `chmod u+x /tmp/myscript.bash`) and then call it, just typing `/tmp/myscript.bash`. You can also save it in one of the `PATH` directories (type `echo $PATH` to see which are they), make it executable and then you'll be able to call it from anywhere, but I don't really recommend doing that because you may end up overwriting juicy system's commands if you're not careful. For instance, let's say you call your script with the unfortunate name of `ls`, save it in the first directory of the `$PATH` (in my case, `/usr/local/sbin`) Every time you type `ls`, you won't be listing directories, but calling your script... Which is bad.

Comment: Would you say that this answer solved your problem? You can mark it as  'accepted' by clicking the tick on the left area of the answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135493/informing-new-users-of-how-to-accept-answers

Comment: No..after reading this i tried myself. First i make file like passwd.Then change my file permission. i did chmod a=rwx filename then i change my code as                                  users=`awk -F '{print $1}' /etc/passwd | sort -u`

for user in $users
do
      echo " - $user"
done

then i get my result now ...